# Multiple Many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, schema, relational-database

I'm new to database design, and I'm wondering what best practice would be to implement something like this in a relational database, MySQL specifically.

Suppose I have the following three concepts

- user: has access to view certain groups of patients
- patient_groups: groups of patients
- patient : discrete people that have to be watched by users

I want users to potentially have access to multiple `patient_group`s, and for patients to be able to exist in multiple patient groups. Therefore, the relationship between `user` and `patient_groups` is many to many, and the relationship between `patient` and `patient_groups` is many to many. I was wondering what the best practice is to set this up in a relational database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to have five tables:

- `users`
- `patients`
- `groups`
- `user_patients`:  association table with one row per patient begin watched by a user
- `patient_groups`:  association table with one row per patient and group

Your description hints at a sixth table:

- `user_groups` with one row per user and group where the user has access to the group.